# How to do TRY_CAST in Snowpark?

Tags: python, sql, casting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am doing `try_cast` as on this column `df.select(split(col("spc_value"),lit("~"))[0])` that has value `"1.419000"`
[image]
with

```
from snowflake.snowpark.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, FloatType, DecimalType, DoubleType, VariantType
from snowflake.snowpark.functions import col,lit,split,try_cast
```

[functions.try_cast](https://docs.snowflake.com/ko/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.functions.try_cast)

```
df.select(try_cast(split(col("spc_value"),lit("~"))[0],DoubleType()))
```

and
column method [Column.try_cast](https://docs.snowflake.com/ko/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/python/latest/api/snowflake.snowpark.Column.try_cast)

```
df.select(split(col("spc_value"),lit("~"))[0].try_cast(DoubleType()))
```

Both attempts return
[image]

> SQL compilation error:
> Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types VARIANT and FLOAT

What have I missed for doing `TRY_CAST` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input of try_cast (whether in Snowflake SQL or Snowpark) ***MUST*** be a string.  In your example, using `split()` creates an object value, so you should explicitly cast that object to a string and then use a `try_cast()` to whatever data type you are trying to get it to.  Please note that `try_cast()` also has a limited set of data types that you can use.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_cast?utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=serp&utm_term=try_cast

Comment: Thanks. prepending try_cast() with to_varchar() helped.
Interestingly this problem in Snowpark did not appear in Snowflake SQL. In SQL, split() produced an array. Selecting the array with index returned content in varchar already.

Comment: That is interesting on the SQL side.  In my experience, SQL returns an object with using an index on SPLIT, but to be honest, I prefer SPLIT_PART() to an index, anyway.